# Pass json string to environment variable in a k8s deployment for Envoy

Tags: kubernetes, envoyproxy

I have a K8s deployment with one pod running among others a container with Envoy sw. I have defined image in such way that if there is an Environment variable EXTRA_OPTS defined it will be appended to the command line to start Envoy.
I want to use that variable to override default configuration as explained in 
https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/latest/operations/cli#cmdoption-config-yaml

Environment variable works ok for other command options such as "-l debug" for example. 
Also, I have tested expected final command line and it works.

Dockerfile set Envoy to run in this way:

```sh
CMD ["/bin/bash", "-c", "envoy -c envoy.yaml $EXTRA_OPTS"]
```

What I want is to set this:

```
       ...
      - image: envoy-proxy:1.10.0
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        name: envoy-proxy
        env:
           - name: EXTRA_OPTS
             value: ' --config-yaml "admin: { address: {  socket_address: { address: 0.0.0.0, port_value: 9902 } } }"'
        ...
```

I have succesfully tested running envoy with final command line:

```sh
envoy -c /etc/envoy/envoy.yaml --config-yaml "admin: { address: {  socket_address: { address: 0.0.0.0, port_value: 9902 } } }"
```

And I have also tested a "simpler" option in EXTRA_OPTS and it works:

```
       ...
      - image: envoy-proxy:1.10.0
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        name: envoy-proxy
        env:
           - name: EXTRA_OPTS
             value: ' -l debug'
        ...
```

I would expect Envoy running with this new admin port, instead I'm having param errors:

```sh
PARSE ERROR: Argument: {
             Couldn't find match for argument
```

It looks like quotes are not being passed to the actual Environment variable into the container...

Any clue???

Thanks to all

Answer (score 1):

You should set `["/bin/bash", "-c", "envoy -c envoy.yaml"]` as an ENTRYPOINT in you dockerfile or use `command` in kubernetes and then use `args` to add additional arguments.

You can find more information in [docker documentation](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/dockerfile_best-practices/#entrypoint)

Let me explain by example:

`$ docker build -t fl3sh/test:bash .`

```
$ cat Dockerfile
FROM ubuntu
RUN echo '#!/bin/bash' > args.sh && \
    echo 'echo "$@"' >> args.sh && \
    chmod -x args.sh
CMD ["args","from","docker","cmd"]
ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/bash", "args.sh", "$ENV_ARG"]
```

```
cat args.yaml

apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: null
  labels:
    run: args
  name: args
spec:
  containers:
  - args:
    - args
    - from
    - k8s
    image: fl3sh/test:bash
    name: args
    imagePullPolicy: Always
    resources: {}
  dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
  restartPolicy: Never
status: {}

Output:
pod/args $ENV_ARG args from k8s
```

```
cat command-args.yaml

apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: null
  labels:
    run: command-args
  name: command-args
spec:
  containers:
  - command:
    - /bin/bash
    - -c
    args:
    - 'echo args'
    image: fl3sh/test:bash
    imagePullPolicy: Always
    name: args
    resources: {}
  dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
  restartPolicy: Never
status: {}

Output:
pod/command-args args
```

```
cat command-env-args.yaml

apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  labels:
    run: command-env-args
  name: command-env-args
spec:
  containers:
  - env:
    - name: ENV_ARG
      value: "arg from env"
    command:
    - /bin/bash
    - -c
    - exec echo "$ENV_ARG"
    image: fl3sh/test:bash
    imagePullPolicy: Always
    name: args
    resources: {}
  dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
  restartPolicy: Never
status: {}

Output:
pod/command-env-args arg from env
```

```
cat command-no-args.yaml

apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: null
  labels:
    run: command-no-args
  name: command-no-args
spec:
  containers:
  - command:
    - /bin/bash
    - -c
    - 'echo "no args";echo "$@"'
    image: fl3sh/test:bash
    name: args
    imagePullPolicy: Always
    resources: {}
  dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
  restartPolicy: Never
status: {}

Output:
pod/command-no-args no args

#notice ^ empty line above
```

```
cat no-args.yaml

apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: null
  labels:
    run: no-args
  name: no-args
spec:
  containers:
  - image: fl3sh/test:bash
    name: no-args
    imagePullPolicy: Always
    resources: {}
  dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
  restartPolicy: Never
status: {}

Output:
pod/no-args $ENV_ARG args from docker cmd
```

If you need to recreate my example you can use this loop to get this output like above:

```
for p in `kubectl get po -oname`; do echo cat ${p#*/}.yaml; echo ""; \
cat ${p#*/}.yaml; echo -e "\nOutput:"; printf "$p "; \
kubectl logs $p;echo "";done
```

Conclusion if you need to pass env as arguments use:

```
    command:
    - /bin/bash
    - -c
    - exec echo "$ENV_ARG"
```

I hope now it is clear.

Comment: Thanks but that's exactly what I do, isn't it?

Comment: No, you are using `CMD` instead of `ENTRYPOINT`, read linked doc to find the defense.

Comment: Hi, really thanks for your detailed and with exhaustive examples. But this is not working for me or I did'nt get the explanation. I did changes as you proposed and tried different combinations, but either I get literally $EXTRA_OPTS or I have overriden the ENTRYPOINT with the command I put but I don't want this and as I explained Iam able to set Env variables but for some reason the quotes are missing. Unfortunately (or not, it depends) I will be on a leave for 6 weeks and I don't think I will be able to continue testing. Thanks for your time

Comment: Just post what you did

Comment: If you still can't make it, it means my answer still requires improvement.